# Node JS server on Shared Hosting - on a specific port using .htaccess

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I seem finally to have found an .htaccess code snippet that makes it possible to run a Node JS server on non :80 port of shared hosting.

From https://medium.com/@mayomi1/how-to-host-a-node-js-app-on-shared-host-52e12a62a259

```
#Open Port
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/$1 [P,L]
```

Seems to be working EXCEPT that it re-routes ALL traffic, port :80 included to the Node Server on :XXXX

I have some additional lines of in my .htaccess, one to convert http to https, the other to handle non-existant paths (go to /specificsubfolder/, passing the non-existant part of the path as a hash)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /specificsubfolder/
#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect non-existant path
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \#$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

What I'm hoping to do (My grasp of .htaccess is very limited):

Traffic on port :80 -- ignore the Node JS server, and do the re-routing / hash thing

Traffic on port :XXXX -- ignore port 80 re-routing above. Handle via Node server.

Comment: Your .htaccess applies to requests send on port 80 or 443 only anyway, because that is where Apache is listening. If you have your Node server listening on port XXXX, and you make your requests directly to port XXXX - then what would you still need any rewriting or proxying for?

Comment: The problem I'm attempting to resolve: This is a shared hosting environment where you cannot open any ports.  The Node server may be listening, but the port isn't open.  The goal is to use .htaccess is to pry open that port.  So far I've had some success (not w/ the above code -- just in testing the ability of .htaccess to open a port).  Unfortunately my understanding of .htaccess is still so limited I barely understand what each line means.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.  Again, still learning `.htaccess`, and currently barely comprehending what the bits of code mean, but here's a solution the problem posed above that seems to be working (the goal here is to have one `.htaccess` file handle a number of things in a way that keeps them from contradicting one another):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /specificsubfolder/

#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]

#trigger that requests to a nonexistent file called 'srvr'
#opens port XXXX re-routes traffic to the node server listening there.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} srvr
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/$1 [P,L]

#redirect for all non-existant paths other than to 'srvr'
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ \#$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Your condition that checks against the `REQUEST_FILENAME` does not "look" right? It matches `srvr` _anywhere_ in the filesystem path that the requested URL maps to. You should probably be matching against a more specific URL-path instead. What URLs are you wanting to fwd to your NodeJS server?

Comment: Thx MrWhite -- My assumption was that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` limits the search to the actual filename of the URL, not the folder path, and because it's in a 'specificsubfolder' it only affects directories from that point down.  Did I get that correct?  For this particular question I wasn't actually interested in forwarding the path to the Node server -- I'm happy to pass POST data to it.  The goal is to open up a port to that server in a shared hosting environment that doesn't otherwise allow you to open up custom ports.

Comment: The `REQUEST_FILENAME` server variable contains the _absolute filesystem path_ (not just the filename) that the request maps to. So, for example, if you requested `example.com/path/to/file.html` (which exists as a physical file) and your document root was `/var/www/user/public_html` then `REQUEST_FILENAME` would contain `/var/www/user/public_html/path/to/file.html`. However, if you requested `example.com/foo/bar/baz.html` (where `/foo/bar/baz.html` is entirely virtual) then `REQUEST_FILENAME` would contain `/var/www/user/public_html/foo` (which might not be quite as expected).

Comment: Your condition may work OK in your scenario, it's just that the usage is unusual. If `srvr` occured anywhere in the filesystem path above the document root, then the condition would always be successful, regardless of the requested URL. I suspect that the more specific `/srvr$` would also be correct and less prone to error? As would `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/srvr$`? "I wasn't actually interested in forwarding the path to the Node server" - although you do appear to be doing this with the `$1` backreference. (?)

Comment: RE: "server variable contains the absolute filesystem path..." - Brilliant. Thank you for clarifying and for including an explainer about those quirks.  Are there ways take the variables that htaccess works with and pass them -- say add them as data to the POST data if only just to more easily learn how htaccess operates?

Comment: RE: "I wasn't actually interested in forwarding the path to the Node server" / "although you appear to be doing this"  -- Yes, indeed, and it does forward, which is cool to see.  It's good to know it's an option.

Comment: Regarding your suggestion: use of ^/srvr$ -- yes I was thinking the same.  Thanks for the example.

Comment: "Are there ways take the variables that htaccess works with and pass them" - You can add them as GET/URL parameters _OR_ set an environment variable and examine this in your script. eg. `RewriteRule ^ - [E=MY_VAR:%{REQUEST_FILENAME}]` - which is less intrusive as it avoids changing the request in any way.

Comment: Fascinating stuff.  I'd heard htaccess was 'really powerful'.  Starting to see it.  Thanks again.